# javac taking atleast 15 minutes to compile on Ubuntu 20.04 using JDK 1.8. If I switch to JDK 11, the behaviour is normal

Tags: java

A simple HelloWorld program is taking 15 minutes to compile using JDK 1.8 on Ubuntu 20.04. It works good again with JDK 11. Not sure what is the issue.

script.sh 
date 
javac Sample.java 
date

~$ sh script.sh
Sun 27 Mar 2022 09:45:24 AM EDT 
Sun 27 Mar 2022 10:02:40 AM EDT

All java variables look good. If there is any syntax issue in the program, it reports immediately. It's taking time to generate .class file.

Comment: Does Sample.java reside on a network file system, or on the system’s own hard drive?

Comment: Own hard drive. It works fine with JDK 11 'javac'. Only issue with JDK 1.8.